# How can you cast to a type in an unnamed namespace in the watch window?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Given:

```
namespace
{
    struct Blah
    {
        int x;
        float y;
        std::string z;
    };
}

Blah x;
```

Add `*(Blah*)&x` in the watch window. It fails to cast and displays an error that the type is unknown. Strangely, it *must* know the type because putting just `x` in the watch window displays correctly.

For reference, I'm adding custom debug visualization for my class by extending `autoexp.dat` and this problem causes my visualization to fail when the template argument of my class is a type declared in an unnamed namespace.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0888kc6a%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

"The native C++ expression evaluator does not support anonymous namespaces."

they suggest using decorated names

Comment: It looks like there is no run-time way to get the decorated name (something I could also put in the watch window). Ugh.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio now has support for this, you can cast to a type in an anonymous namespace like this:

```cpp
*(`anonymous-namespace'::Blah*)&blah
```

Source: [developer community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/support-anonymous-namespaces-in-the-debugger/388773#T-N1247399)

Comment: Sadly this does not work for me in MSVS2022, even with the cast the data members are not visible.